# Why getting differences between using XCode and xcodebuild?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcodebuild

Can anyone explain why I get different results when compiling the same XCode 4.x project using the GUI and xcodebuild command-line?

**XCode GUI**

1. Perform a clean
2. Build "Release" target
3. Build successfully

**xcodebuild**

1. Perform a clean
2. Run "xcodebuild -configuration Release"
3. Results in the following errors:

   /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -Os -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -fvisibility=hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -c "/Users/XXX/Extensions/NSFileManager_Extensions.m" -o "/Users/XXX/Developer/Intermediates/YourApp.build/Release/YourApp.build/Objects-normal/ppc/NSFileManager_Extensions.o"
   /Users/XXX/Extensions/NSFileManager_Extensions.m:15:60: error: ToxicRegularExpressions/ToxicRegularExpressions.h: No such file or directory
   ** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC "/Users/XXX/Developer/Intermediates/YourApp.build/Release/YourApp.build/Objects-normal/ppc/NSFileManager_Extensions.o" /Users/XXX/Extensions/NSFileManager_Extensions.m normal ppc objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_0

And finally **GUI + xcodebuild**

1. Perform a clean in GUI
2. Build "Release" target
3. Builds successfully
4. Run "xcodebuild -configuration Release"
5. Builds successfully

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the SDK on the command line, like so:

```
xcodebuild -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator3.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. The problem was NOT solved by adding the -sdk option

Answer (score 1):

Specify the **scheme** you want to build with `-scheme`. Without it `xcodebuild` may use the "legacy" **target** driven build system, which is different. You may want to make some of your schemes shared for this, when redistributing projects.

See: Postscriptum of [xcodebuild driving me nuts again with a zombie OBJROOT](https://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/weblog/2015/xcodebuild_driving_me_nuts_ag.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one version of XCode installed? If so, this answer to a related question might solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11129067/567039

Comment: Just one XCode version installed