# xcodebuild uses different configuration than building from within Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build, xcodebuild

At the command line, xcodebuild gives different results than building from within the Xcode UI.

Here is the command line that I pass:

`$ xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator5.0 -configuration Release -scheme mylib -target mylib`

It may be important to note that the target is set to create a static library file.

I know that different settings are being used because I have -Wundeclared-selector toggled off in the project file.  However, I get these warnings when running xcodebuild from the command line.

It seems that others are also having this problem:
[Why does xcodebuild give different build results than XCode UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653065/why-does-xcodebuild-give-different-build-results-than-xcode-ui)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had multiple versions of Xcode installed on my machine.  This fixed it:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Comment: Thanks Parveen, I'd been tearing my hair out over this. You could mark your own answer as the correct answer.

Comment: I was using two different version of Xcode, and building using xcodebuild was failing while Xcode built successfully. This saved wasting my hours.